# Photoshop: implementing color picker into an action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

So here's the short version: I have web banners I create on a daily basis. There is a border and then some colored text and graphical elements within it. I have already created an action that lets me pick an image for the banner depending on what the ad is, however, I can't seem to figure out a way to make it so that I can pick a color from the image and then have that color passed on to the colored elements (border, text etc).

I want to use the modal option within the actions to allow myself to pick the color for each banner I create, but as I mentioned before, I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Is this even possible with an action, or does it require scripting?

*Note: using (PS CC 2015.5)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any way to make it stop and wait for an input with the basic actions function. However, if I'm understanding what you are trying to achieve then there may be a method that will not add any additional complication to your workflow...

When you set up your action, add all of the elements to be coloured into a layer mask, rather than keeping each of them as separate elements. (It might be desirable to keep editable versions of these elements on separate layers in case you need to go back and change them.) Once you have built the layer mask (and the action has finished running) you can then apply the desired colour to the fill of the layer with that mask. The border, text, etc will then all be rendered in the colour that you choose.

If this doesn't work for you, please share an image of one of your banners so that I (or someone else) can give you more specific help.